# Reorder URL query string alphabetically

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a query string that looks something like this...

`let badString = "dogs=c,b,a&cats=z,y,x";`

Using vanilla javascript or the lodash framework I am trying to rearrange the key and values into alphabetical order, so it would end up like...

`let goodString = "cats=x,y,z&dogs=a,b,c"`

Comment: You can first split the String with delimiter and then concatenate back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const goodString = badString.split('&').sort().map(val => {
    let [k,v] = val.split('=');
    return [k, v.split(',').sort().join(',')].join('=');
}).join('&');
```

Comment: Excellent, but just in case it's not clear, if one needs to use it on all URLs, regardless of whether they contain multiple query params or not, one must first check for the presence of the `&` character, otherwise return the `badString` as is.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let badString = "dogs=c,b,a&cats=z,y,x";

var array = badString.split("&");
var newArray = [];

array.forEach(function(e) {

  newArray.push(e.split('=')[0] + '=' + (e.split('=')[1]).split(',').sort().join());
  
});

var goodString = newArray.sort().join('&');

console.log(goodString);
```

Comment: This does not sort the values internally.  Please check the output specified by the OP.